# React Native - How to overlap margin?

Tags: css, react-native

I have web apps background and been working with CSS for quite a while now.

That said when I have 2 blocks of `div` with `margin: 15px`, assuming the blocks displayed in a row direction. In CSS, I'm gonna have 2 blocks of `div` with `15px` whitespace between them. However, using the same logic to React Native, what displayed is 2 blocks of `div` with `30px` margin.

It looks like the margin is not overlapping in contrast with CSS logic.

Is there any way I can get around this or am I missing something?

Web:
[image]

React Native:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Margin overlap is not present in `react-native` the same way as CSS. For a quick fix, you can use `marginLeft` and `marginRight` styling in the react native StyleSheet.

```
block1: {
    marginLeft: 15,
    marginRight: 7.5
},
block2: {
    marginLeft: 7.5,
    marginRight: 15
}
```

For a more well rounded approach, use `justifyContent` (This style should be applied to the parent view outside both blocks)

```
container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around'
}
```

But keep in mind this won't give exact 15px margin between everything like you wanted.